# Objective-C to JavaScript call not happening

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, cordova

I am using Phonegap/Cordova(2.1.0) to create IOS app. I want to call a JavaScript function in index.html file of the Phonegap from an Objective-C function. So, I am creating an instance 'theWebView' of the 'UIWebView' class like below:

Code in AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject < UIApplicationDelegate > {
    NSString* invokeString;
    
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView* theWebView;
```

Code in AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize theWebView;
```

And code for calling JavaScript function is as follows:

```
// to call javascript function 
    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myJavascriptFunction()"];
```

The code is successfully getting built. But, the JavaScript function 'myJavascriptFunction()' defined in script tag of index.html is not getting called. How can I do this?

I am attaching the web-view load code also, which exists in MainViewController.m file. Since, I am using Cordova 2.1.0, separate files exist for ViewController and AppDelegate
classes.

```
/**
 Called when the webview finishes loading.  This stops the activity view and closes the imageview
 */
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad function");
    
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    
    return [ super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView ];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad function");    
    return [ super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView ];
}

/**
 * Fail Loading With Error
 * Error - If the webpage failed to load display an error with the reason.
 */
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog(@"didFailLoadWithError function");
    return [ super webView:theWebView didFailLoadWithError:error ];
}

/**
 * Start Loading Request
 * This is where most of the magic happens... We take the request(s) and process the response.
 * From here we can redirect links and other protocols to different internal methods.
 */
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    
    NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest function");
    
    // Intercept custom location change, URL begins with "js-call:"
    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"js-call:"]) {
        
        // Call the given selector
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"resetBadgeCount")];
        
        // Cancel the location change
        return NO;
    }
    
    // Accept this location change
    return YES;
    
}
```

The code in index.html around the javascript function 'myJavascriptFunction':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="iui/iui.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" title="Default" href="iui/t/default/default-theme.css"  type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="iui/t/default/iui-custom.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function myJavascriptFunction()
            {
                alert('myJavascriptFunction');
                
                return;
            }
            
            </script>
        
    </head>
    <body id="bd">
    </body>
</html>
```

I am attaching the Objective-C code to load the index.html file and then call the JavaScript function :

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"www"];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSString *myFile = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];
    
    NSLog(@"base url= %@",myFile);
    
    NSData *myFileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
    NSString* myFileHtml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myFileData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    
    [theWebView loadHTMLString:myFileHtml baseURL:baseURL];
    
    // to call javascript function 
    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"onDeviceReady()"];
```

I am thinking problem is with the last line.

Comment: Show the code where you load the WebView

Comment: hi im try thing same thing, how did you get it to work in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you have problem with this code. Here everything looks ok, but you should check that `myJavascriptFunction()` that you are calling if it is working ok. You can try maybe from browser with JavaScript console and see if it is going to work when called manually.

For example code for myJavascriptFunction that works for me is:

```
        function myJavascriptFunction()
        {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
        }
```

<s>While alert code is not showing any alert and specially not `UIAlertView`.</s>

I stand corrected here regarding alerts, UIAlertView is displayed on Javascript alert event.

Comment: it is there in the script tag of the index.html. I am not very sure if this is where it will look for the javascript function. i am attaching the index.html code also. This issue is very important for me. It has become a huge bottleneck and i can't progress further without solving it. thanks.

Comment: Like I said, error is in Javascript code. You can't call `UIAlertView` by calling `alert` in Javascript. To call it you need to implement that in delegate.

Comment: so u mean to say alert() will not work. But apart from that, the normal javascript code written inside the js function will work ..right? if u could elaborate a little, i will be grateful. anyways, i don't need alert() in my code. that was just for testing.

Comment: yes, like I said, the code is working but not the alert code, you can test with some other code in that function and you will see that it's working properly.

Comment: Then it has to be something with your phonegap/cordova. Check here sample project that works with both UIAlertView and redirect. Check sample here: http://cl.ly/001B0i3r0p3Y

Comment: Thanks a ton for your valuable help. i think i am close. In your code, you have an event on which you are calling the two functions. In my case the js function is to be called at some point in objective-c code. If we can solve how to establish that, i am thinking we will solve this.

Comment: i have attached the objective-c code i tried at the last in the original queston. @Amar Thanks again.

Comment: I would try something else instead `onDeviceReady`, replace it with some other Javascript method just to see if Javascript is started at all. One more thing. If you are loading contents of UIWebView on `viewDidLoad` it's possible that it's executed so fast that you don't get notification `onReady` called properly so you can try to add one button on the view that would call Javascript method just to test that it's working and then move it further to code to be executed after some period of time or when notification arrives.

Comment: Well i already tried other method. It dint work. i am thinking, the statement to call the js method is not correct.

Comment: Well you saw test project that I have created and how do I call them, nothing strange there, you are doing the same. Create new test project and see if your UIWebView in it will respond on Javascript method calls. It could be like I said that you have some error in .js files included in .htm file and because of it the rest of the file where your method is is not loaded.

Comment: @AmarKulo hi there! im using this same method in my `appdelegate.m` to call a function after i receive push notifications and open a particular page in my cordova app. I'm not getting it to work, help please.

Comment: What method @Gallwynmasc? Maybe you can start your own question and get help easier?

Comment: @AmarKulo hi thanks for the reply, I used a different method and solved the issue.