# Syntax to call javascript function from objective-c

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, cordova

I am making an app in IOS with phonegap/cordova 2.1.0 framework. I want to invoke a javascript function residing inside index.html from objective-c. So, first i am loading the index.html and then trying to call the javascript function. My code is as under:

```
 NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"www"];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSString *myFile = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];

//NSLog(@"base url= %@",myFile);

NSData *myFileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
NSString* myFileHtml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myFileData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

[theWebView loadHTMLString:myFileHtml baseURL:baseURL];

// to call javascript function 
[theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"onDeviceReady()"];
```

The second last line loads the index.html and the last line calls the function inside it. But, somehow the above code is not working. Am i going wrong somewhere syntax wise.

Alos, since the index.html is already being loaded before, so how can i specify the file name(ie. index.html) where the function exists without loading it once again? Thanks.

Javascript function is as follows:

```
function onDeviceReady(callback) {

                var item = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
                var message = "deviceready localStorage.getItem('key')="+item+" localStorage.length="+window.localStorage.length;

                if( item == null){
                    item = "";
                }
                item = item + "value";

                window.localStorage.setItem("key", item);

                var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");

                if ( deviceType == 'android' && gAppControl.loadScript == false ){
                    loadScript('iscroll.js');
                    gAppControl.loadScript = true;
                    document.addEventListener("backButton", backPressed, false);
                }

                var db = window.openDatabase(dbName, "1.0", gAppConfig.dbMessage, 200000);

                db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB , callback);

                // return
                return;
            }
```

Comment: you mean somehow or sometimes?

Comment: i mean always the code is not working.. :)

Comment: The objective-C code is okay. Show me the js code.

Comment: add try-catch around the js-function, is there any error?

Comment: i have attached the j-s code.

Comment: @clint i'm trying your code from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14134196/3421340) to call a function on receiving notifications in `appdelegate.m`. Have you got this approach to work? I can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
onDeviceReady()
```

this is the phonegap API, if the device is not ready, you will fail to call any Phonegap plugin, so What's the detail in the onDeviceReady() function? any phonegap-plugin involved?

The code seems no problem, and here is my [code](https://github.com/meadlai/MDCommonWebView), with a bridge to comunicate with Objective-C and HTML-Javascript,

Comment: onDeviceready is just the name of the function. It has nothing to do with device is ready or not. My question is, Is my last line of code correct? Is it the right syntax to call a function in javascript?